# Why do I have to refresh a WordPress Site several times for it to appear?

Tags: wordpress

This site that I've created, www.aroundtownnews.com sometimes has to be refreshed 2, 3, or 4 times which is frustrating.

The page mostly in question is:

http://aroundtownnews.com

If you move your mouse over the background, you'll see the cursor "pointer" appear as if there's something covering the entire page.

This was built in Wordpress and is upgraded to most recent version and I just can't seem to understand why this is happening.

Thank you

UPDATE:

How to reproduce the problem:

1) Go to **www.aroundtownnews.com** and see the DOCK and OCEAN no page, no menu, no anything, just the background

2) Refresh the screen, 1, 2 or 3 times to "eventually" see the page, menu, header, footer, etc...

That's how to reproduce the problem. Hope this helps understanding why my customer and I am upset.  I"m frustrated.

**UPDATE:**

I found this code in the scripts.js file because of Garr Godfrey.

```
$('.mh-slider-widget').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    controlNav: true,
    directionNav: false,
});
```

I commented it out and sure enough, everything works GREAT!

Now, the second part of this question is:  If you go to READ ONLINE, and click on the Issue for any month, the FLIPHTML will appear. That works great, but, when you close it, there's another one right behind it! I followed the instructions and have been using FLIPHTML5 for 2 years and they have no solution.

Here's the code for each issue:

```
<div class="team_style_featured">
    <h4>JAN 10 - 23, 2020 Issue</h4>
        <div class="image">
        <img class="imgcovers tip" title="Read our January 10 - 23, 2020 issue of AroundTown News today!" src="http://aroundtownnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Jan-10-2020-23-2020-Page1thmb.png" alt="" data-rel="fh5-light-box-demo" data-href="http://online.fliphtml5.com/sner/ghuu/" data-width="900" data-height="500" data-title="Read our JAN 10 - 23, 2020 Full Issue - Click the THREE VERTICAL DOTS for FULL SCREEN MODE" />
        </div>
        <a href="http://www.aroundtownnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/publications/Jan-10-23-2020-full-issue.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Download/Read PDF</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you're hitting a problem with flexslider. Look at the javascript console. It's not immediately clear why it's undefined since the plugin code is right before it.

Comment: I'm not using flexsider.

Comment: Unless....let me check... stand by

Comment: That did it... FRAK!  It must've been an orphan code that I put there thinking I was using Flexislider. Thank you so much!

Comment: Garr, make this a solution and I'll vote for you, sir.  THANK YOU!

Comment: I can't see the 2nd part because right now you've got another error. "animsition" is undefined. misspelled or missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer this with a tip for debugging javascript issues, which is what I think you are experiencing.

First thing is to check javascript console. In Chrome is easiest, just hit F12. A window should open and click the "Console" tab to see javascript errors, as well as other warnings.  You can even click on the line number to open up the code to where the error occurred.

The other tip is to use the "Inspect..." from the right mouse menu. You can look at which elements in your DOM are currently visible.

One common thing I've encountered if I seem to have duplicate containers is that the handlers may be registered more than once. Using jquery, if you use "on" or some other technique to add a handler multiple times, the handler is called multiple times.

You can insert log messages to debug. Things like:

```
 console.log("in click handler")
```

This will be visible in the javascript console and you can see if it shows more than once (careful, as chrome consolidates duplicate messages. Instead of printing twice a number just shows up next to the output).

That should get you to be able to resolve these on your own much faster.

Comment: Garr, thanks, buddy... I'll vote you up on this but I've been in IT for nearly 40 years and Chrome and Canary are what I use. I code in Angular 8, Node, Bootstrap 4.x, Typescript, NPM, and more. Internet Exploder is something we never use and FF doesn't work with natural language processor like Chrome does. We're still on the bench with that.  BTW, I did exactly that, saw the error, then went into WORD press under Appearance -> Theme Editor -> scripts.js and COMMENTED out that nasty code. POOF! You helped me tremendously. I had put it there, thinking I was going to use Flexislider at one time.